# syntax highlighting in docbook

Tags: xslt, xalan, docbook

I use xalan-j_2_7_1 and docbook-xsl-1.76.1 to generate documentation. I saw in [hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/), that they use syntax highlighting in there code. How can i do it in my doc?

Answer (score 4):

Check out the `highlight.source` parameter:

```
<xsl:param name="highlight.source" select="0"></xsl:param>
```

> When this parameter is non-zero, the
>   stylesheets will try to do syntax
>   highlighting of the content of
>   programlisting elements. You specify
>   the language for each programlisting
>   by using the language attribute. The
>   highlight.default.language parameter
>   can be used to specify the language
>   for programlistings without a language
>   attribute. Syntax highlighting also
>   works for screen and synopsis
>   elements.

Reference: [DocBook XSL Stylesheets: Reference Documentation](http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/doc/fo/highlight.source.html)

Comment: Thank you. It works. But i prefer hibernate's styles. What do they use?

Comment: Sorry, cant't help you with that.

Comment: @Daniel: the Hibernate docs use a library called JHighlight. I don't know if it's available anymore; the https://jhighlight.dev.java.net/ home page is gone.